# Android : How to listen MediaPlayer event like music play/stop?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

Does it exists a broadcast receiver action in order to listen a Media Player event such as the detection of the music starting to play/stop or the detection of the hit of Play/Stop Button of the MediaPlayer ?

More generally I'd like to detect when the audio stream is starting/ending.

Thanks

Comment: Really nobody knows the way to detect that a song is played on Android ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `requestAudioFocus()` to register an audio focus listener on a stream which you want to listen on. You don't need to play this stream actually.

When you get `AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS`, it means another *"audio stream is starting"*.
When you get `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN`, it means another *"audio stream is ending"*.
If you are interested in music stream, `isMusicActive()` may also help you.